# Why did SQL Server suddenly decide to use such a terrible execution plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

**Background**

We recently had an issue with query plans sql server was using on one of our larger tables (around 175,000,000 rows).  The column and index structure of the table has not changed for 5+ years.

The table and indexes looks like this:

```
create table responses (
    response_uuid uniqueidentifier not null,
    session_uuid uniqueidentifier not null,
    create_datetime datetime not null,
    create_user_uuid uniqueidentifier not null,
    update_datetime datetime not null,
    update_user_uuid uniqueidentifier not null,
    question_id int not null,
    response_data varchar(4096) null,
    question_type_id varchar(3) not null,
    question_length tinyint null,
    constraint pk_responses primary key clustered (response_uuid),
    constraint idx_responses__session_uuid__question_id unique nonclustered (session_uuid asc, question_id asc) with (fillfactor=80),
    constraint fk_responses_sessions__session_uuid foreign key(session_uuid) references dbo.sessions (session_uuid),
    constraint fk_responses_users__create_user_uuid foreign key(create_user_uuid) references dbo.users (user_uuid),
    constraint fk_responses_users__update_user_uuid foreign key(update_user_uuid) references dbo.users (user_uuid)
)

create nonclustered index idx_responses__session_uuid_fk on responses(session_uuid) with (fillfactor=80)
```

The query that was performing poorly (~2.5 minutes instead of the normal <1 second performance) looks like this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[response_uuid] AS [response_uuid], 
[Extent1].[session_uuid] AS [session_uuid], 
[Extent1].[create_datetime] AS [create_datetime], 
[Extent1].[create_user_uuid] AS [create_user_uuid], 
[Extent1].[update_datetime] AS [update_datetime], 
[Extent1].[update_user_uuid] AS [update_user_uuid], 
[Extent1].[question_id] AS [question_id], 
[Extent1].[response_data] AS [response_data], 
[Extent1].[question_type_id] AS [question_type_id], 
[Extent1].[question_length] AS [question_length]
FROM [dbo].[responses] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[session_uuid] = @f6_p__linq__0;
```

(The query is generated by entity framework and executed using sp_executesql)

The execution plan during the poor performance period looked like this:

[image: execution plan]

Some background on the data- running the query above would never return more than 400 rows.  In other words, filtering on session_uuid really pares down the result set.

Some background on scheduled maintenance- a scheduled job runs on a weekly basis to rebuild the database's statistics and rebuild the table's indexes.  The job runs a script that looks like this:

```
alter index all on responses rebuild with (fillfactor=80)
```

---

The resolution for the performance problem was to run the rebuild index script (above) on this table.

Other possibly relevant tidbits of information... The data distribution didn't change at all since the last index rebuild.  There are no joins in the query.  We're a SAAS shop, we have at 50 - 100 live production databases with exactly the same schema, some with more data, some with less, all with the same queries executing against them spread across a few sql servers.

**Question:**

What could have happened that would make sql server start using this terrible execution plan in this particular database?

Keep in mind the problem was solved by simply rebuilding the indexes on the table.

Maybe a better question is "what are the circumstances where sql server would stop using an index?"

Another way of looking at it is "why would the optimizer not use an index that was rebuilt a few days ago and then start using it again after doing an emergency rebuild of the index once we noticed the bad query plan?"

Comment: Perhaps this similar question on dba.stackexchange will provide some insight: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/when-should-i-rebuild-indexes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is simple: the optimizer changes its mind on what the best plan is. This can be due to subtle changes in the distribution of the data (or other reasons, such as a type incompatibility in a `join` key). I wish there were a tool that not only gave the execution plan for a query but also showed thresholds for how close you are to another execution plan. Or a tool that would let you stash an execution plan and give an alert if the same query starts using a different plan.

I've asked myself this exact same question on more than one occasion.  You have a system that's running nightly, for months on end. It processes lots of data using really complicated queries. Then, one day, you come in in the morning and the job that normally finishes by 11:00 p.m. is still running. Arrrggg!

The solution that we came up with was to use explicit `join` hints for the failed joins. (`option (merge join, hash join)`). We also started saving the execution plans for all our complex queries, so we could compare changes from one night to the next. In the end, this was of more academic interest than practical interest -- when the plans changed, we were already suffering from a bad execution plan.

Comment: thanks for your answer, based on your comments I added some additional information in my question and posed the question a couple different ways

Comment: @JeremyDanyow . . . The answer is that statistics on the tables were out-of-date.  If you have a long process, you might want to update the statistics before running it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) or at least periodically.  As a note:  my problem was actually different.  The statistics were correct, the optimizer just chose the wrong path.

Comment: My question mentioned there's ~175,000,000 rows in the table.  In my last update I mentioned the data distribution didn't change.  Here's some more info on that:  less than 10k rows were added since the last index+stats rebuild.  With this additional info do you still think the stats were out of date?  I'm skeptical because 10k rows wouldn't move the stats.  Also mentioned in the update we have many other dbs with the same schema and queries and we've never hit something like this where simply rebuilding an existing index magically fixed the problem.  Your insight on this is much appreciated.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow . . . It pretty much *has* to be statistics of some form or other.  The choice of execution plan is made by the optimizer, which is basing its decisions on what it knows about the table.  If that gets out of date, then the wrong decision can be made.  Rebuilding an index does rebuild some statistics (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48991/does-a-re-index-update-statistics), which can affect the plan.

Comment: ok I guess this means I need to recheck with the DBAs to confirm the weekly index rebuild and stats update actually happened.  Is there such thing as a "broken index"- ie are there situations where the optimizer says "I can't use this index it's corrupt"?  If so, how would one monitor for that?  I also recall one of the DBAs mentioning that Idera reported the index was "ok" while the issue was occurring.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "_Or a tool that would let you stash an execution plan and give an alert if the same query starts using a different plan._" - Hey, you are now covered with SQL Server 2016 [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store) ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is one my most hated issues with SQL - I've had more than one failure due to this issue - once a query that had been working for months went from ~250ms to beyond the timeout threshold causing a manufacturing system to crash at 3am of course. Took awhile to isolate the query and stick it into SSMS and then start breaking it into pieces - but everything I did just "worked". In the end I just added the phrase " AND 1=1" to the query which got things working again for a few weeks - the final patch was to "blind" the optimizer - basically copying all passed parameters into local parameters. If the query works off the bat, it seems like it will continue to work.

To me a reasonably simple fix from MS would be: if this query has been profiled already and ran just fine the last time, and the relevant statistics haven't changed significantly (e.g. come up with some factor of various changes in tables or new indexes, etc), and the "optimizer" decides to spice things up with a new execution plan, how about if that new and improved plan takes more than X-multiple of the old plan, I abort and switch back again. I can understand if a table goes from 100 to 100,000,000 rows or if a key index is deleted, but for a stable production environment to have a query jump in duration to between 100x and 1000x slower, it couldn't be that hard to detect this, flag the plan, and go back to the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Newer SQL Server versions have a great new feature called "Query Store" where you can analyse recent queries performance.

If you see a query that sometimes uses a "fast" plan and sometimes a "slow" one - you can force the fast plan. See the screenshot. The "yellow circle" plan is the fast one, but the "blue square" plan is not (it's higher on the "duration" chart")

[image: query store]

Comment: This is the solution when it is not possible to modify or add hints to queries. That is the case when queries are produced dynamically, or they come from an application that doesn't allow updating the queries. Commercial software or license/support agreements may prevent changes to source code/queries, so this solution should get more votes.