# Simple SQL Server query always time out

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, timeout, sqlperformance

We have a stored procedure that has been working perfectly for over 10 years. A few days ago it started timing out. I run it from the Query console in SQL Management Studio and it timesout. I restart the server and then it runs in 1 second...

Comment: Did you actually have a question here?

Comment: Sounds like the query got a bad plan.

Comment: your plan is corrupted i guess...next time it timesout clear cache and check

Comment: @SeanLange, it's quite obvious, we don't know what's going on here.

Comment: @SteveB what do you mean?

Comment: @Sameer what do you mean? How do I do that? Why this started to happen after 8 years every day?

Comment: this can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851857/why-did-sql-server-use-such-a-terrible-execution-plan-all-of-the-sudden

Comment: What @SeanLange was alluding to is, "How do you expect someone to answer this question with what you have provided?". Any attempt to answer this would start by either asking a ton of questions, or taking shots in the dark at the array of reasons this could be happening. The problem could be completely unrelated to this query... i.e. another query or operation could be the real issue and you are just noticing side effects. It's like me saying "My car has been running fine for 10 years, but now it skips sometimes, and turning it off an on resolves it for a while".

Comment: Yeah @scsimon pretty much nailed it. We don't know what is happening. Two quick possibilities that come to mind. It could be a bad execution plan or blocking. Either of which might be solved by a restart. My guess is that is a poor execution plan. Assuming that you need to know why the plan is bad. It could be due to a LOT of things, the most likely is that you have reached a "tipping point" with the amount of data which causes a less than optimal plan. But with no details it is impossible to say for sure. And even less possible to help fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the changes happened to your system over these 10 years, maybe you have added some background services that is doing some heavy sql updates/insertions while you are running your query.

I think you can have a clear vision on the performance of your query if you run it on a staging server or a local machine( which normally have a different load of sql operations ), observe the time it takes to execute your query, do your tries from time to time.

If the execution time of your query on staging server is constant, then your query is not the cause of the issue.